# Determining all extensions of a field morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Consider the field morphism $\sigma: \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2), \sqrt2 \mapsto - \sqrt2$.
I am trying to find all extensions $\overline{\sigma}: 
L \rightarrow L$ of $\sigma$, where $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$.

(Note: I mean "extensions" as in extension of a function (field morphism), not "field extension". Those are defined as:
Let $K(a)/K$ be a field extension and $\sigma: K \rightarrow L$ be a field morphism. A field morphism $\overline{\sigma}: K(a) \rightarrow L$ is called "an extension of $\sigma$ onto $L$" if $\overline{\sigma}_{|_K}=\sigma$
)

The first step is to calculate the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt3$, $m_{\alpha, \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)}$

I assume that $m_{\alpha, \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)}=x^2-3$, and because $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]=2$, I know that $m_{\alpha, \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)}$ has to have degree $2$.

The next thing is to calculate $\sigma(x^2-3)$
$\sigma(x^2-3)=\sigma(1)x^2-\sigma(3)=x^2-3$

I know that for every root r of $\sigma(x^2-3)=x^2-3$, there exists a extension $\overline{\sigma}: (\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2))(\sqrt3 ) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2))(\sqrt3 )$, such that $\overline{\sigma}(\alpha)=r$, in my case this means:

$\overline{\sigma_1}(\sqrt3)=\sqrt3$ and

$\overline{\sigma_2}(\sqrt3)=-\sqrt3$

Question Nr.1 Is the calculation of $\sigma(x^2-3)$ correct? Since there where no $\sqrt2$ or multiples of it in the coefficients, I get the results I got.

Question Nr.2 Are my calculations of the extensions of $\sigma$ correct? (If the awnser to Nr.1 is no, then if the approach for the extensions is correct.)

Comment: Both of your calculations work.

Answer (score 1):

Extend $\sigma$ and define $\sigma(x)=x$.
Then $\sigma(x^2-3)=x^2-3.$ and the calculation is correct.

Remark:
Now, extend $\sigma$ and define $\sigma(x)=-x$ or $\sigma(x)=x+1$.

Then $\sigma(x^2-3)=\sigma(x)^2-3 \neq x^2-3$ for the latter case.

---

Only focus on the case extending $\sigma$ to $\hat{\sigma}(x)=x+1$.

Let $f(x)=x^2-3$, $\alpha = \sqrt 3$.

Then $\hat{\sigma}(f(x))=(x+1)^2-3$ and $\gamma := -1\pm \sqrt 3$ (pick any one) is a root of $\hat{\sigma}(f(x))$.

Here I use the same symbol $\hat{\sigma}$, to map $\alpha$ to $\gamma +1$

Note that $\hat{\sigma}(\alpha)=\gamma +1$ and it is a root of $f(x)$.

$\hat{\sigma}(\alpha)=\gamma +1=\pm\sqrt 3$ so the result is the same.

Remark: $\gamma +1$ is not a root of $\hat{\sigma}(f(x))$ and it is different for the case if we choose $\hat{\sigma}(x)=x$.

For the general case, the result is the same if $\hat{\sigma}$ is an isomorphism... and there is not a "must" to fix this mapping.

Comment: But you can extend the isomorphism $\sigma$ to $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]$, by defining $\sigma(x) = x$.

Comment: @Anton Odina We should not fixed it?
As we want to find the different extensions, and it should be all maps that map a root to its conjugate.

Comment: It's just a variable (not dependent of $\sqrt{2}$ or $\sqrt{3}$); it doesn't affect your calculations of determining the conjugates.

Comment: Really thanks for you pointing out this. I think we need to pick a suitable choice, and it is natural to define $\sigma(x)=x$.
I am not sure whether we can make arbitrary choice for $\sigma$, and to keep $F=L$ for $\overline{\sigma}: L \rightarrow F$.

Comment: There is not need to make this choice, even more there is no need to calculate $\sigma (x)$ as $\sigma$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ and the result is the same up to isomorphism $\hat{\sigma}$.